# c program to remove elements from given linked list and print the entire list after removing

Tags: c, linked-list, singly-linked-list

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>

struct Stud
{
    char name[20];
    struct Stud *next;
};

struct Stud *hptr=NULL,*tptr;
//char data[20];


void deleteKey(struct Stud *hptr,char data[20])
{
    struct Stud * temp = hptr, *prev;
    while (temp != NULL && temp->name == data)
    {
        hptr = temp->next;
        free(temp);
        temp = hptr;
    }
    while (temp != NULL)
    {
        while (temp != NULL && temp->name != data)
        {
            prev = temp;
            temp = temp->next;
        }


        if (temp == NULL) return;


        prev->next = temp->next;

        free(temp);


        temp = prev->next;
    }
}




void createList(char *s)
{
    struct Stud *nptr;
    nptr=(struct Stud *)malloc(sizeof(struct Stud));
    strcpy(nptr->name,s);
    if(hptr==NULL)
    hptr=tptr=nptr;
    else
        tptr->next=nptr;
    tptr=nptr;
    nptr->next=NULL;
}


void display(){
    while(hptr!=NULL)   {
        printf("%s ",hptr->name);
        hptr=hptr->next;
    }


}


void main(){
    int i,n;
    char str1[20];
    char s[20];
    scanf("%d",&n);
    for(i = 0; i < n; i++)  {
        scanf("%s",str1);
        createList(str1);
    }
    scanf("%s",s);
    display();
    deleteKey(hptr, s);
    display();
}
```

I am not getting the desired output.please correct me in passing the arguments to deleteKey and suggest me if there is anything wrong in the code.
        for example:
            input:
        5
        kmit
        jntu
        snist
        cbit
        ngit
        cbit
        output:
        kmit
        jntu
        snist
        ngit

Comment: Can you please edit your question to contain a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)? Also when doing that also include, for some specified input, the actual and the expected output.

Comment: For a start: `... && temp->name == data` you cannot compare character arrays and strings like this.

Comment: Use `strcmp` to compare char arrays. [strcmp](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strcmp/)

Comment: please help me with the code to modify

Answer (score 0):

You have to pass the head node to the function by reference because it can be changed within the function.

Also you have to use the standard function `strcmp` to compare strings.

In this expression

```
temp->name == data
```

there are compared addresses of the first characters of two arrays and it is obvious that they are unequal.

Here is a demonstrative program that shows how the function can be implemented.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

struct Stud
{
    char name[20];
    struct Stud *next;
};

int deleteKey( struct Stud **head, const char *name )
{
    while ( *head && strcmp( ( *head )->name, name ) != 0 )
    {
        head = &( *head )->next;
    }

    int success = *head != NULL;

    if ( success )
    {
        struct Stud *node = *head;
        *head = ( *head )->next;
        free( node );
    }

    return success;
}

int push_front( struct Stud **head, const char *name )
{
    struct Stud *node = malloc( sizeof( *node ) );
    int success = node != NULL;

    if ( success )
    {
        strncpy( node->name, name, sizeof( node->name ) );
        node->name[sizeof( node->name ) - 1] = '\0';
        node->next = *head;
        *head = node;
    }

    return success;
}

void display_list( struct Stud **head )
{
    for ( struct Stud *current = *head; current != NULL; current = current->next )
    {
        printf( "%s ", current->name );
    }
}

int main(void) 
{
    struct Stud *head = NULL;

    push_front( &head, "Bob" );
    push_front( &head, "Peter" );
    push_front( &head, "Margarite" );

    display_list( &head );
    putchar( '\n' );

    deleteKey( &head, "Margarite" );

    display_list( &head );
    putchar( '\n' );

    deleteKey( &head, "Bob" );

    display_list( &head );
    putchar( '\n' );

    deleteKey( &head, "Peter" );

    display_list( &head );
    putchar( '\n' );

    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
Margarite Peter Bob 
Peter Bob 
Peter
```